# Magento Theme Fall-back / Hierarchy in the light of custom theme and third-party extensions

Tags: theme, extensions

I've been looking into how Theme Fall-back / Hierarchy works since CE 1.4 and I think I've fairly well understood it.

Then I move a legacy theme (the names `purple-mix` and `purple_theme` following are exemplary) which had been put inside the legacy locations:

```
app/design/frontend/default/purple-mix
skin/frontend/default/purple-mix
```

Those files have now been moved into the more appropriate, namespaced and currenlty as best-practice suggested ones:

```
 app/design/frontend/purple_theme/purple-mix
 skin/frontend/purple_theme/purple-mix
```

This so far looks fine to me and is more or less just context of my question. It gets more interesting when I add magento extensions / modifications into the mix.

Some third-party plugins now have placed files into the old (and according to [*What About `default/default`?* (*Magento's Theme Hierarchy Changes in CEv1.4 and EEv1.8*)](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy#3.2) deprecated) location (even that plugin for example is a Feb 2014 release).

If I read the documentation it's now the case, since the moment I activate the new theme `purple_theme`, the fall-back to `default/default` will not be triggered any longer. Is this correct?

And so I now wonder what is best to do. Should I duplicate (copy) all those files into my own theme's `default` directory (`purple_theme/default`)? Or should I move those files?

Or should I copy/move them into `base` instead (the extension files in question are within their own sub-directory, e.g. for the Payone plugin, it's `skin/frontend/default/default/payone/core/mandate.css`)? What would be recommended practice here?

From my own (so far limited view, I don't have that much Magento experience), I tend to moving those files into `base/default` so that *every* theme will benefit from the extensions changes (I also have the full tree under Git version control, so I'm sort-of relaxed that file-changes are easily tracked).

Also is it good practice to discuss this with extension developers? What are common guidelines to give to them?

I've seen [Custom Package/Theme for Admin module that falls back to default package?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/14111/4115) which is about admin configuration (and version 1.8) so I'm not sure if it would apply for frontend as well (and if already since version 1.4).

I even think about having something like [*Magento Enterprise Theme Fallback (Sonassi)*](https://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/magento-enterprise-theme-fallback/) with the difference, that I don't want to have fall-back to `frontend/enterprise/default` but `frontend/default/default`. Via [*Theming - starting from scratch*](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/3780/4115).

(Exemplary extensions that are in use: One-Step-Checkout, Payone and Customer-Credit; Currently on an outdated 1.4 version, as you can imagine this is also in the light of upcomming Magento upgrades)

Comment: this may help you to understand why files where they are :)
http://blog.belvg.com/magento-fallback-configuration-default-and-specific-themes-packages-design-exceptions-temporary-theme-configuration.html

Comment: @StefanGregori Thanks for the link, I understand the hierarchy, but I wonder how to deal with files from extensions that do not play with exactly that hierarchy (or which assume there are only themes within the "default" namespace)

Comment: well, as i unterstand it, theire files should always be in base/default just because they can not know the name of your custom theme folder! but then, if you make changes to them, make a copy to your custom theme because with that, the extension stays upgradeable and your changes wont get overwritten.

Comment: @StefanGregori: That is also what I tend to: Extension should place their "core" stuff into base/default despite Magento docs warn about this. I probably will revive `default/default` with some plugin so that there is another middle-layer for fall-backs.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned you have the full project under git so I would suggest moving these files to `base/default`, comment/document etc what has happened so that you know when/if you update these extensions what you need to do.

Finally feel free to contact the extension developer, they will normally be happy to help and welcome new ideas.