# How to override template in magento 2.0?

Tags: template, theme, overrides, magento-2.0

Based on the theme development documentation http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html here I could create a space for new theme in magento 2.0 but overriding the base template become more difficult to understand like altering page layout etc.

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Please explain what exactly you don't understand in the documentation. What did you already do? What are you currently trying? Maybe this topic helps you: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112655/theming-for-magento-2-starting-from-scratch

Answer (score 0):

I am sure about you have just create magento 2 theme in your project.

So You have to just override templates into your custom theme folder from core module.

We have given here module-catalog template to override,

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/
```

You can change as per your module override template file instead of `Magento_Catalog`

Just keep same manner in default module **view** folder file in above custom theme location.

please let me know if you have any issue