# How can I start custom theme development from scratch in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, theme, development

I have installed Magento 2.1.1 version. I am familiar with the functions which are used in the admin panel of the magento2.1.1 but now i want to develop custom theme.

> What are the prerequisites to develop custom theme from scratch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some excellent resources you can find by searching. I added some useful links, hope those can help you.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

[Theming for Magento 2 - Starting from scratch](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112655/theming-for-magento-2-starting-from-scratch)

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-custom-theme-magento-2-part-1/

http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-a-new-magento-theme/