# how i set the checkout cart xml file in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout

This is my code in magento1

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
    <label>Shopping Cart</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>
        <reference name="root">
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    <reference name="checkout.cart">
        <action method="addItemRender">
            <type>simple</type>
            <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block>
            <template>designtool/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>

</checkout_cart_index>

<checkout_onepage_review translate="label">
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="addItemRender">
            <type>simple</type>
            <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block>
            <template>designtool/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_review>

<sales_order_view translate="label">
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="sales/order_view" name="sales.order.view">
            <block type="sales/order_items" name="order_items" template="sales/order/items.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_item_renderer_default</block><template>designtool/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>designtool/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</sales_order_view>

<!--<sales_email_order_items>
    <reference name="items">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>designtool/email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</sales_email_order_items>-->
```

how can I set this xml file in magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

in magento,Layout **files are created**  basic of ***handle name*** `default.xml,checkout_cart_index.xml,catalog_product_view.xml` etc.

So, i want want to change something on layout than  you copy create those  layouts at `app/design/vendor/theme/[ModuleName]/`

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/debug-theme.html

[Theming for Magento 2 - Starting from scratch](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112655/theming-for-magento-2-starting-from-scratch)

Comment: thanks for reply but i want in custom extension not in theme