# Steps for theme development

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have just started with the theme development in the magetento 2.1. I am over all new to magento. I wanted to know the setup and the ways to one develop a theme in magento . After a lot of reading the procedure i follow after making a change in the custom theme file is

1. When changing/overriding the layout file run the 'php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme vendor/theme' command.
2. When changing/overriding the less files/static files using grunt i run 'grunt exec:vendor && grunt less:vendor'. (Offcourse after configuring grunt).

But if instead of modifying the files from the app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/ if i modify the less/static files from 'pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme/en_US/' I can just run grunt less:vendor and i can get the compiled css there and after my development is done i can copy the files back to app/design/frontend folder at respective places.

What are the best practices or the common way of theme development steps?

PS: All vendor is your vendor and all theme is respective theme name.

Answer (score 1):

#### Question 1 - PHTML templates and layout XML changes

For development purposes you should be running in [developer mode](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html), to check this you can run `php bin/magento deploy:mode:show`. If you need to set it to developer mode use `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`.

When in developer mode you do not need to run the `static-content:deploy` command, this is only for production mode. All you'll need to do when changing a layout or template file (PHTML) is to clear your cache (layout and block cache if you want to be specific).

#### Question 2 - Static assets (JS, CSS etc)

When changing static assets you do not need to run `exec`, this sets up symlinks so it's only useful when you have added or removed a file. If all you have done is change some styling you'll only need to run the `grunt less:theme` task.

If you've changed other static assets such as Knockout HTML templates or a JS file in most cases clearing your browser cache is enough.

If you make a change and it isn't being shown no matter what you do it's normally a good idea to clear the following directories:

```
var/view_preprocessed
var/cache
var/page_cache
pub/static/frontend
```

And if it's backend/module related also remove

```
var/di
var/generation
```

### Links

And for an answer on how to develop a theme from scratch please see my answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112655/theming-for-magento-2-starting-from-scratch/113592#113592).

I'd also recommend reading the [front-end dev docs pages](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html)

Comment: How about if i am adding a new play_layout apart from "1column.xml" etc
I tried that but it is not coming in the dropdown of the new page that i create from the admin panel.

Comment: You'll likely need to clear cache and possibly log out of the admin then log back in. If this doesn't work I think there is something wrong with the code.