# Error 503 Backend fetch failed

Tags: magento2, error, backend, custom-theme

I'm trying to create a new theme by following

'http://devdocs.magento.com/…/front…/themes/theme-create.html' or

'[Theming for Magento 2 - Starting from scratch](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112655/theming-for-magento-2-starting-from-scratch)'

this tutorial but once everything was done then I'm getting this annoying error: [image: (picture attached)]

P.S: I have cleared all cache, reindex, deploy-static, maintenance:disable and things like that. At the moment I've installed Magento on a bitnami instance.

Does anyone have such an issue with his/her experience?

Comment: check error log

Comment: This error means that you have error in scripts and Varnish cache can't get page content from php.

It may be permissions issue. In Bitnami documentation they suggest to do follow in case of 500 errors:
`
sudo find /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo chmod +x /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/bin/magento-cli
sudo chown -R daemon:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var
`

Check error log of your web-server. You'll get idea what's wrong.

Answer (score -1):

If you have used varnish cache then,

Please review https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/varnish/tshoot-varnish-503.html