# Best pratices to update the module-checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, theme, template, overrides

I want to add some custom text **test** to my **mini top cart** in my theme **header section**. I see it is located here:

```
public_html/m2/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml
```

When I edit this file and clear cache I can see my **test** showing on the site fine,

However a friend of mine told me I should not be editing files located in `/vendor` directory

So if I wanted to add my `minicar.phtml` with my own text inside this where would I add this file in my theme ? which directory would override me needing to edit any files in vendor?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation:**

Yes, **rule number 1**, you must never update a native magento folders why ? there are several reasons and the **most common** is : if one day you have to update your Magento or install some patch you will have errors and you lose your updates because you have updated that files ! and you need to do that manually one by one and it's not practical !

**Solution:**

To update some files from a **native Magento modules** you can either `rewrite the module` or either `updating it in the current theme`. And since you want just to update a phtml file so **the best way** is to override it in your current theme.

So you copy your file from:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml
```

to:

```
app/design/frontend/{YourVendorName}/{YourThemeName}/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml
```

Dont forget to **clean the cache** and **deploy the static-content** by launching these commands:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 1):

Chances are, you'll want to set up a theme if you haven't already.  [Here is some information on that](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/114015/33071).  For now, I will assume that you are using the Luma theme, but you can replace the `Magento/Luma/` part of the path with `[vendor]/[theme]` once you have created a theme folder.  Copy the file that you found under `vendor/..` to the location below and edit away!

`/app/design/frontend/Magento/Luma/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml`