# Parent theme necessary?

Tags: magento2

I am creating custom theme in magento 2. Is it necessary to assign parent theme to my new custom theme.

```
 <parent>Vendor/theme</parent>
```

I want to develop whole things from the scratch, that's why I don't want to include parent theme.

Comment: no need if you develop everything on your own, if not you suppose get basic thins like parent styles and layout from parent theme. That's why we include parent theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not necessary, if you do not set a parent theme you can create all your CSS from scratch. See this post for an example - [Theming for Magento 2 - Starting from scratch](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112655/theming-for-magento-2-starting-from-scratch/113592#113592)

Answer (score 4):

> Parent theme is not necessary to defined it

It is not necessary to define parent theme check  [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/113592/68695) 
 also if you do not set a parent theme you can create all your own CSS of theme becuase it is scratch 
  also if you want to create your parent theme in template,layout,css,extension then here [available](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.3-develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/blank)

Comment: What if I want to create all the thing (property, layout, template files, and styles) in my new theme. Do I need to use parent theme now?

Comment: No you don't need but that doesn't make sense, you can customise anything by inheriting parent theme instead of creating all the page layouts from the scratch @MuhammadBilalkhan

Comment: i know customiza all thing in custom theme but sometime is needed is parent theme check default reference : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html @MuhammadBilalkhan

Comment: Thanks @PrathapGunasekaran, I think I am getting your point

Comment: Thank Rakesh for the answer

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran can you copy your comment to answer?

Comment: Rakesh. +1 for your support and your effort

Comment: @RakeshDonga has given the same, do accept this answer because that doesn't make sense provide repeating answer for single question.Hope you understand

Comment: That's acceptable. Thanks @PrathapGunasekaran for your support

Comment: The whole point of creating a theme from scratch is to not use the parent theme.

Comment: Also, templates, layouts javascript etc. are defined in modules not the parent theme. The default themes mostly contain CSS, check https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.3-develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/blank out.

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran thanks i have updated it