# Magento 2.1.8 dev site catalog search and products listing redirecting to live site

Tags: magento-2.1, products, redirect, catalogsearch

I have setup my magento 2.1.8 EE live site on staging for development. The homepage, admin and cms pages are working fine. But my prduct pages are redirecting to live site and catalog search also redirects to live site.

Please provide a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: you have run reindex command?

Comment: php bin/magento indexer:reindex into your root and make sure you don't use any extension for search if so remove the live credential from staging and do it @chanchal

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran Thank you so much resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you didn't do reindexing after imported your LIVE database,

Run this command in your magento root

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

and if you're running multistore and having a large data, avoid running the above command and be specific to the requirement.

Run below commands to know the list

> php bin/magento indexer:info
>
> Eg : php bin/magento indexer:catalog_category_product

Hope this helps .

Comment: i have allready comment in first run index command mate :)

Comment: So what? If you want to give it as an answer yes you can, the thing to make this question as mark-able. @RakeshDonga so I can delete this

Comment: no i will just tell you if question solve by comment then why add to new answer

Comment: If someone new comes they won't be probably seeing comments @RakeshDonga If anything which are provides information that's good to go with answer isn't it?

Comment: ok no problem thanks for new user helping

Comment: sarcastic ? am not the one who answer just for reputation FYI https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266097/parent-theme-necessary/266098#266098

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91300/discussion-between-rakesh-donga-and-prathap-gunasekaran).