# Magento 2.3 | Starting with Theming

Tags: magento2, theme, resources, learning

Given Scenario:

For learning and understanding the Magento 2 Theming Stuff better and get a closer look i woud like to create my own theme from scratch. I want to create a basic one, no backend options like all the fancy ones out there. To begin i want to use the utility framework tailwindcss and expand from there. Since im new to all this, especially with magento i'm looking for a few good resources to start reading / watching ( videos prefered since i can understand stuff better with a visual representation ).

Are there any resources out besides the Magento docs where i can get a good look? I want everything indepth to get as much infos as possible, probably explained in an easy path.

Things im looking especially for are the following:

- Understanding the xml files
- Change the column layouts in order to use tailwinds grid
- Change templates to use with tailwind
- custom functionality ( for example: hide all "special prices" on a toggle switch )

Comment: The answers here should help you - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112655/theming-for-magento-2-starting-from-scratch/113592#113592 - there isn't a difference between the M2 versions when it comes to creating a theme from scratch

Answer (score 1):

If you want learn a very basic thing you should follow:

webKul Blog:

https://inchoo.net/category/magento-2/

https://www.mageplaza.com/

But if you want to learn all magento thing conceptually No one better than below blogs:

https://devdocs.magento.com/#/individual-contributors

https://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2/

Hope this helps you.