# Magento 2.4 custom theme (no parent) how to go further?

Tags: magento2, theme

I'm really new to magento and was asked to remake our old theme (shopify store) in magento.
I've chosen to create a theme without a parent so i could have more control, following this tutorial to create it https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

This all works fine, but now i don't know how to go on from here, do i need to start creating new layouts or can i just start adding css to the theme. (I only need to remake the header and footer.)

Also, how can i remove or hide the unwanted sections like newsletter signup for example?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Magento I highly recommend using a parent theme otherwise you are going to have to build the CSS and JS for every feature on the frontend yourself and that will require advanced Magento knowledge.

If you insist on creating it from scratch then your next steps will be to add some CSS and begin overriding layout XML and PHTML files as per your customisations.

Guides for that can be seen in the dev docs:

- [Layout XML](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html)
- [Adding CSS](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html)

I've shown some brief initial steps for it on another answer - [Theming for Magento 2 - Starting from scratch](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112655/theming-for-magento-2-starting-from-scratch/113592#113592)